# cakephp make same query recursive

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I have a site develop in cakephp 2.0.
I have a table "Product" related to property with hasMany, and HABTM to Product. A product can contain many product and that product can contain many product. I can have multiple level of product. 
To make this relation I have used this model (explained into this question: [cakephp HABTM same model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773185/cakephp-habtm-to-the-same-model)):

```
class Product extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Product';
    public $useTable = 'products';
    public $belongsTo = 'User';
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');

        public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Ingredient' => array(
            'className' => 'Product',
            'joinTable' => 'ingredients_products',
            'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'ingredient_id', 
            'unique' => true
        )
    );

}
```

I know how to retrieve product example: I have a product that contain other product I make a find with condition and I retrieve all data with their property like this:

```
$this->set('product',$this->Product->find('all', array(
                    'contain' => array(
                            'Property',
                            'IngredientProduct'
                        ),
                    'conditions' => array('id' => $id)  
                )));
```

(IS ONLY AN EXAMPLE THE QUERY I DON?T KNOW IF IS GOOD DEPENDS OF MANY THINGS IS ONLY AN EXAMPLE)

But if I find 3/4 product inside my product and if findedproduct contain other product how can I do that? Because I don't know how many "levels" I have I can have 1 level or 6 level of product. A product contain many products, this finded products contain other products ecc..
How can I do that and retrieve for each product its property? It's a recursion query but the problem is that I don't know how many level I have. Some ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Containable does not traverse so deep. I would advice to unbind your associations and join tables manually. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470182/how-to-change-the-sequence-of-joins-in-cakephp) to see an example and at [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables) cookbook chapter (you need to know SQL in your case). Or you can use [TreeBehavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html) as Dave suggested.

Comment: But I have to make a nest join right? a join inside a join inside a join until a product doesn't have a product inside it right? But my problem isn't how to make the query but how to make a recursive query to retrieve all product until a product doens't have a product inside it

Comment: As I wrote you need to know SQL to perform such complex queries. Take a look at this question about recursive queries http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646833/using-mysql-query-to-traverse-rows-to-make-a-recursive-tree So, I guess, that is not an option for you, so use TreeBehavior. Maybe it would generate more than one query but it is easy to use.

Comment: I know SQL and I don't want to use the easy way but the best and perform way because I have a lot of records to retrieve. I try with TreeBehavior and the join. I don't know if TreeBehavior is my way

Comment: There is no build-in option for recursive queries in CakePHP if that is what you wanted to ask. There is topic on complex queries in the cookbook - http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions. So, if you decide to go this way read it. You can also construct query "by hands" and pass it to your model: `$this->Product->query('YOUR COMPLEX QUERY');`

Comment: I'm thinking to try a thing like that: a query to retrieve the first level of product, for each product a make another query ad add it to my previous array into a loop for every level. Is complex, but this evening I try to make the join level

Comment: In that case better use TreeBehavior. It will construct these queries for you and will save your time (if you can modify your database schema, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could/should go with something like - all products are just in "products" table, then you have a tree table that keeps the entire product hierarchy?

Comment: I don't understand totally.. can you make an example to clear my problem?